# Port 22: Connection refused for new users on remote server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote

When I create new users on my remote server (Ubuntu 14.04) I am unable to connect as those users through SSH:

```
ssh test@SERVER.IP
ssh: connect to host SERVER IP port 22: Connection refused
```

ufw is running with port 22 enabled (I am simultaneously connected through ssh as a different user!) so I'm completely stumped as to why no new users can connect via ssh/sftp. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Do you allow password-based authentication, or just key-based? Do you have any Allow/Deny stanzas (for users or groups) in the server's sshd_config? How exactly did you create / configure the new accounts?

Comment: And can you connect with the old users? How do the debug log look like? `ssh -vvv test@SERVER.IP`